# Rounded rectangle background editext with hint in left top of background border

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

I got stuck in creating UI. please help me out creating that .

I have a EditText having rounded rectangle border which is ok but placeholder is in the top of border leaving the border.

Here is the image

[image: edit text with border]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a relative layout consisting of edittext and textview and then use your drawable background to particular layout and add text and edittext hint

Comment: @ysl i want background to be transparent as i am having background image on screen.

Comment: then don't set background color to your drawable

Comment: if so that background line crosses the textview used as a hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [Vector Drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html) for creating custom shape as you need.

I have created a sample for the same.
Create **custom_vector.xml** file under *res/drawable/*

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="20dp"
    android:width="20dp"
    android:viewportWidth="400"
    android:viewportHeight="400">

    <group
        android:pivotX="10.0"
        android:pivotY="10.0">

        <!-- the outside box -->

        <!-- top line & top left corner -->
        <path android:pathData="M 30 60 H 40 c -40 0 -35 0 -35 35 "
            android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="10" />

        <!-- left line & bottom left corner -->
        <path android:pathData="M 5 64 v 271 c 0 40 0 35 35 35 "
            android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="10" />

        <!-- bottom line & bottom right corner -->
        <path android:pathData="M 30 370 h 330 c 40 0 35 -10 35 -35"
            android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="10" />

        <!-- right line & top right corner -->
        <path android:pathData="M 395 356 v -261 c0 -40 0 -35 -50 -35"
            android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="10" />

        <!-- top line till end-->
        <!-- 140 is the starting point of line after TEXT-->
        <path android:pathData="M 140 60 370 60"
            android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="10" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

You may have to change the value of last path tag

> top line till end

as per your text at the place of *'Name'*. You can also modify the shape or corners as you want.

Create a **test_layout.xml** file under *res/layout/*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#faffd5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_vector"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="Name"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Alex Smith"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It appears like this screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try below...

you achieve this using `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/edittext"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edittext"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="107dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="90dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

round.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" android:width="@dimen/_1sdp"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Output : [see](http://prntscr.com/gt5f6u)

Comment: thanks but i am having the background image all around the screen so i want the ui to transparent so that background image will not affect

Comment: got your point... I will update you if I found some exactly you like.